# How do I choose between regression methods for inference?

Tags: regression, logistic, estimation, inference

Suppose my goal is to understand the relationship between variable $y$ and covariates $X$. Let's say $y$ is a rate, the number of success in $n$ trials, therefore bounded between $0$ and $1$.

Now I have (at least) 2 approaches. Take the log of $y$ and use a linear model, or use logistic regression. Logistic regression is the more theoretically appropriate model but estimation can lead to problems ([example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/511777/why-do-ols-and-logistic-regression-coefficients-have-opposite-sign)) that the linear method doesn't have.

How do I choose between them when the goal is understanding, not predicting? I thought of using AIC or a similar criterion but the target is not the same so I don't think that will work.

Comment: You actually probably want s quasi-Poisson model with an offset, not logistic or linear regression. The QP model is appropriate for counts and rates.

Comment: That's 3 models on the table now. I'm still not sure how I can balance the theoretical appropriateness of them vs. accurate estimation and stability.